# How do I delete a key and its nested key value pairs in a json file?

Tags: python, json

I want to be able to check if a json file has the top level key I'm looking for and delete that nested dictionary.

Json file:

```
{
    "One": {
        "action": "One",
        "delay": 1559243024.3665395,
        "seconds": 0,
        "score": 0,
        "delta": 1559183024.3665395,
        "grace_sec": 60000
    },
    "Two": {
        "action": "Two",
        "delay": 1559321009.969849,
        "seconds": 0,
        "score": 14,
        "delta": 1559261009.969849,
        "grace_sec": 60000
    },
    "Three": {
        "action": "Three",
        "delay": 1559909745.5981774,
        "seconds": 0,
        "score": 0,
        "delta": 1559309745.5981774,
        "grace_sec": 600000
    },
    "Four": {
        "action": "Four",
        "delay": 1559909757.0363235,
        "seconds": 0,
        "score": 1,
        "delta": 1559309757.0363235,
        "grace_sec": 600000
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried so for but hasn't worked:

```
if name == child.text:
              ...
                with open("streak.json", "r+") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)

                for x in data:
                    if name in x:
                        del x[name]

                with open("streak.json", "w") as file:
                    data = json.dump(data, file)
```

So for instance if the name == "Two", then all of Two's key value pairs would be deleted including Two itself.

Comment: So you want to delete `"Two": {
        "action": "Two",
        "delay": 1559321009.969849,
        "seconds": 0,
        "score": 14,
        "delta": 1559261009.969849,
        "grace_sec": 60000
    },` ?

Comment: It's not Two, I want to delete but any dictionary that the program says == child.text. I was just using Two as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`pop()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) function. This function will delete the key from the dictionary and return the value. If the key does not exist, it will return a default value.
eg:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d.pop('a', None)
1
>>> d
{'b': 2}
>>> d.pop('c', None)
>>> d
{'b': 2}
>>>
```

This will reduce the burden of checking if a key exists or not when deleting and you won't have to rely on `KeyError` to check if it failed.
You can check if the return value is not your sentinel value, `None` in this case, then the key was successfully deleted. If it is the sentinel value, then the key never existed.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the top level item:

```
with open("streak.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

if name in data:
    del data[name]

with open("streak.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(data, file)
```

Comment: Sorry, I just copied the code from the OP.